# Spark container not hiding contents outside of its body

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

This is what what my screen looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

It is composed like this :

```
First container <s:HGroup>(900 X 100)--top black area

Second container <s:Group> (900 X 475)--middle white area

Third container <s:HGroup>--(900 X 100)--bottom black area
```

If the project were done with Flex 3, the middle area would be an `<mx:Canvas>`.

Now suppose I have one BorderContainer(125 X 475) and name it **middleContainerChild**.  It is located on the right side of the middle area. When I set its `y` postion to `-middleContainerChild.height`, it should be located at `y = -475`, outside of the container's body. And as you can see in the image above, it has been placed there.

But other than with `<mx:Canvas>`, the image still shows, even though it is no longer within the `<s:Group>`s body, and it is rendered "on top" of the `<s:HGroup>`.

See the image below for more clarification:
[image: 2 images showing the problem]

If I use `<mx:Canvas>`, it is hidden away properly, but if I use a Spark container (not only a group, but any Spark container), it remains visible.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Your question was very hard to understand, so I tried to improve the wording and gave it a more precise title.  I hope I got the meaning correctly - please reply if I misunderstood!

Comment: Thanku weltraumpirat, i was in my office at that time, and i was a bit confused, how the people will understand , what i want,so i used images here, thanx for this editing, i appreciate :)

Comment: wow, amazing, u just made it very easy understand, gr8 brother, i learnt one new thing today, thanx for this great help, plzz put your comment in my answer, i'll vote that up :)

Comment: Nah, thanks - keeping everything nice and understandable is part of what StackOverflow is about.  A thank you is quite enough :)

Comment: well said, wish u a great time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a bit about `clipAndEnableScrolling` property of `GroupBase` class.

Regards.

Comment: thnx 2DH :) it's related to what i am looking for :) actually i was not even very clear in the above question, but you have picked the right point, thankeu again  :)

Answer (score 1):

As 2DH gave me the hint, i have prepared this sample,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="900" minHeight="672">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Move 
            id="moveUp" 
            yFrom="0" 
            yTo="-475" 
            target="{helpWindow}"/>
        <s:Move 
            id="moveDown" 
            yFrom="-475" 
            yTo="0" 
            target="{helpWindow}"/>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function buttonUp_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                moveUp.play();
            }

            private function buttonDown_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                moveDown.play();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0"/>
    </s:layout> 

    <s:BorderContainer 
        backgroundColor="#000000" 
        height="100" 
        width="100%"/>
    <s:Group 
        height="475" 
        width="100%" 
        clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

        <s:VGroup 
            left="0" 
            top="0">
                <s:Button 
                    label="Play Effect UP" 
                    click="buttonUp_clickHandler(event)"/>
                <s:Button 
                    label="Play Effect DOWN" 
                    click="buttonDown_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:VGroup>


        <s:BorderContainer 
            id="helpWindow"
            backgroundColor="#CCCCCC"
            y="{-helpWindow.height}"
            right="0" 
            height="475" 
            width="125"
            />
    </s:Group>
    <s:BorderContainer 
        backgroundColor="#000000" 
        height="100" 
        width="100%"/>
</s:Application>
```

so now i have set my center container's **clipAndEnableScrolling** to **true**, and problem solved

Thanks to both the stack members:)